# Rails app will not load file from lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use a mixin method called `to_bool` for class `String` in my Rails applications:

```
class String
  def to_bool
    return true if self == true || self =~ (/(true|t|yes|y|1|byapplication)$/i)
    return false if self == false || self.blank? || self =~ (/(false|f|no|n|0|disabled)$/i)
    raise ArgumentError.new("invalid value for Boolean: \"#{self}\"")
  end
end
```

I just put it in a file called `<app_root>/lib/string.rb`. Works fine in one application.

In a new application I'm working on, it refuses to work. I can make it work in the console if I `load` it first, but it absolutely will not load on its own. It's in the `lib` directory!!! And I have this in my `application.rb`:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/lib
  #{config.root}/app/workers
  #{config.root}/app/inputs
  #{config.root}/lib/mixins
  #{config.root}/lib/classes
  #{config.root}/lib/database
  #{config.root}/app/api
  #{config.root}/app/datatables)
```

It's right there at the top. No matter what I do, I get `NoMethodError` in the console until I:

```
load 'string.rb'
```

What simple thing am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way autoload works is that if a constant **is not already defined** then the autoload_paths are checked for a file matching that constant, and if it exists then that file is loaded.

`String` (obviously :) already exists, so the autoload of your `lib/string.rb` will never be triggered.

You should put it into `config/initializers/core_ext.rb` or something like that.

Comment: You are both a gentleman and a scholar. I did exactly as you said and it worked immediately.